# Draw ellipsis (three dots) between nodes in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I am beginning to learn tikz to draw a simple graph. I would like to represent the idea that there are `N` nodes by drawing something like this:

[image]

How can I draw an ellipsis: `...` between the two nodes?

Here is the code I used for the above:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=2.5cm,
    main node/.style={thick,circle,draw,font=\sffamily\Large}]

    \node[main node] (1) {$X_1$};
    \node[main node] (2) [right of=1]{$X_N$};
    \node[main node] (5) [below of=1]{C};

    \path[every node/.style={font=\sffamily\small}]
        (1) edge (5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

(Other comments on how to improve my tikz code are welcome.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Another way would be to say `\path (1) -- node[auto=false]{\ldots} (2);`. You've turned on the `auto` setting in the `tikzpicture` options, `auto=false` turns it off.

Also, it is recommended to load the `positioning` library and use `right=of` instead of saying just `right of=`. See [Difference between "right of=" and "right=of" in PGF/TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9386).

Finally, I don't really think the `[every node...` option to your last path does anything.

```
\documentclass[12pt,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=1.5cm,
    main node/.style={thick,circle,draw,font=\sffamily\Large}]

    \node[main node] (1) {$X_1$};
    \node[main node] (2) [right=of 1]{$X_N$};
    \node[main node] (5) [below=of 1]{C};

    \path (1) edge (5);

    \path (1) -- node[auto=false]{\ldots} (2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Interesting about the `positioning`! +1 :D

Answer (score 12):

You can add a node, without any border, and use `\ldots`.

The syntax `at ($(1)!.5!(2)$)` means "place it at half distance between `1` and `2`". This requires the `calc` library.

One more thing: I switched from `arrows` to `arrows.meta` because the former is deprecated. See the [Tikz manual](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) (*16.5 Reference: Arrow Tips*, page 203) for more details on how to define the arrow tips. Alas, the tips are a bit different, if you want it round add `>={Stealth[round]}`.

**Edit**: Apart from the fixed positioning, I placed your node options in a `\tikzset`, see the new code, and used `\draw () -- ();` instead.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows.meta,positioning}

\tikzset{
    every node/.style={font=\sffamily\small},
    main node/.style={thick,circle,draw,font=\sffamily\Large}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>={Stealth[round,sep]},shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=2.5cm]

    \node[main node] (1) {$X_1$};
    \node[main node] (2) [right =of 1]{$X_N$};
    \node[main node] (5) [below =of 1]{C};

    \node at ($(1)!.5!(2)$) {\ldots};

    \draw (1) -- (5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```